# How to build bag of phrase (and remainging words) in pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
I love you baby
I love stackoverflow
I have stackoverflow account
```

What I want

```
I Love        2
stackoverflow 2
you           1
baby          1
I             1 # the other two already on "I love"
...
```

What I want is if there's any more than one word that come more than once in dataframe is on my bag of phrase

Comment: Just using bag of words

`pd.Series([y for x in df.values.flatten() for y in x.split()]).value_counts()`

Comment: `I love` are two different words. If you are planning to combine, you will need some logic. Else , you can count all possible non-repeating combination of words using itertools.

Comment: Yes, that what I ask, he idea btw, I still read the documentation of itertools, thanks for thttps://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite sure pandas doesn't have a ready to go tool for this case.

You need to execute algorithm:
In this case I can think about something like this:

1. split all the text to one array
2. in the end of each line add unique word (like: end_of_line_01, end_of_line_02, etc.)
   so after it you have array like this:

> I, love, you, baby, end_of_line_01, I, love, stackoverflow,
>   end_of_line_02, I, have, stackoverflow, account, end_of_line_03

3. take the first 2 words and search in the array if this words exist in any other place in the array in the same order. 
     a. if yes keep the result of how many time. and try the same with one more words
     b. if not count only the first word.
   in the end of this step remove the words that been taken and add it to the result
4. repeat step 3
5. remove all the unique words the you add from the final result